# Migrating content with referenced taxonomy field is to be migrated by term name

Tags: taxonomy-terms, migrations, plugins

Is it possible to migrate content with term reference fields, but instead of referencing terms by their tid they are referenced by their term name?

instead of this:

```
field_tags:
  plugin: sub_process
  source: field_tags
  process:
    target_id: tid
```

Do something like this:

```
field_tags:
  plugin: sub_process
  source: field_tags
  process:
    target_id: [term name]
```

Comment: You have migrated the terms in another migrate or you have already terms ?

Comment: I did not migrate terms.  I created terms on the Drupal 8 site.  This is a Drupal 7 to Drupal 8 migration.

Comment: OK, i guess you should use entity_lookup plugin see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins/list-of-process-plugins-provided-by-migrate-plus

Answer (score 4):

i guess [`entity_lookup`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/migrate_plus/blob/HEAD/src/Plugin/migrate/process/EntityLookup.php) what you looking for:
here is an example from ***migrate_plus/src/Plugin/migrate/process/EntityLookup.php***

```
field_tags:
       plugin: entity_lookup
       source: tags
       value_key: name
       bundle_key: vid
       bundle: tags
       entity_type: taxonomy_term
       ignore_case: true
```

Comment: I will try this out this week and give you an update.

Comment: [field_tags] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [tid] => 1931
                )

        )

I performed a dump of the source data coming in from Drupal 7.  There is no name attached to the term, only a tid.  Does this mean migrating by term name is not possible?